# delete and then insert for incremental load - SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis-2012

I am not aware of anyone doing this as its not documented on any of the forums I have read. Basically I am trying to load from a table that has over 50 million rows. The table takes to long to do a truncate and load technique. I have looked at the following methods

1) CDC (not supported) by our CRM system (SQL server) but is the most preferred method according to what I read

2) Lookup task with No Matched and Matched with use of Split Condition storing Sources Data that Don't Match column by column e.g src.col1 != Dest.Co11. 
src.col1 will be stored onto a staging table to update the destination.
This method can be cumbersome especially if there are loads of columns as there can't be nulls, I have issues with this method for date fields where we have nulls.

3) Okay now come to my idea of deleting modified rows, luckily we have a CreatedOn and ModifiedOn columns on every table. First thing I do in an execute SQL task is to delete the data from the last 5 days using something like below.

```
 delete from table 
 where (CreatedOn between getdate()-5 and getdate)
 Or (ModifiedOn between getdate()-5 and getdate)
```

Then I just basically pull data back from the 5 days in the dataflow task in the source.
     Select * from table
     where (CreatedOn between getdate()-5 and getdate)
     Or (ModifiedOn between getdate()-5 and getdate)

then I use the Lookup Not Matched transformation in SSIS to bring back all new rows. This means not having to deal with Updates using split condition. As the rows are being deleted which have been modified and then inserted using the Not Matched to bring back data that are in the source but not in destination.

Just wondering what People's thoughts are on this, is there something I have missed. I have done some basic test and data looks okay. But I am just curious why this isn't really documented as a method for incremental Loading.

Just want your thoughts on this and whether anyone has tried this method?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a natural key made up of a few fields?

Comment: Yes Natura/business Key which is being used in the lookup transform

Comment: So, instead of deleting, I'd use `MERGE` and the `createdon`/`modifiedon` dates to process the incremental changes. Use SSIS to land the incremental data, and SQL to handle the upsert via `MERGE`.

Comment: I looked into merge actually forgot to mention it above which is similar  to using split condition using or condition for each columns but can be very cumbersome. But just wondering if there is anything wrong with the technique that I have overlooked, as it gets away from doing updates as it deletes then inserts so data is always new?

Comment: `MERGE` doesn't seem cumbersome to me, I agree using SSIS for this can be cumbersome, but with `MERGE` you'd just need to handle `NULL` for your key fields, not all fields. Your approach is not uncommon, I guess the downside is just that you have a window where the data is not in the table between deleting and re-inserting, and it might perform more slowly than `MERGE`. There can also be implications for indexes.